# why git push origin master does not work?

Tags: git, github

I modify my local file. I commit locally and it's ok. But when i push to github, i have the message that all things are update. Here is the command and its result :

```
git push origin master
```

I have the following error message :

```
Everything up-to-date
```

Then to see what happen, i run gitK command and i have :

[image]

I don't understand why i am getting this error ? Why i cannot push my code to github ?

I run the command :

```
git status
On branch dev-branch
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   deploy/openshift (modified content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: I (literally) don't understand that image.  What happens if you look at the history in the GitHub web UI?  Does the latest commit match your latest local commit?

Comment: Can you include the text you get when running `git status` please ?

Comment: I dont speak much french but is it saying that "local modifications are not registered inside the index and not commited" ?

Comment: You need to add any new files created to the index. Do this with the `git add <filename>` command

Comment: there are not new files to add all new files were already added

Comment: You are on dev-branch and pushing the master branch. Thats totally clear for me why git responds like that.

Comment: What to do i have to push on dev-branch ?

Answer (score 2):

According to your `git status` message, you are on branch `dev-branch` not `master`.

When you `git push origin master` the last parameter is the branch name. You have commits in a branch named `dev-branch` not in `master`, so pushing `master` does not have any changes to push.

You probably either want to:

```
git push origin dev-branch
```

which would create the `dev-branch` branch on GitHub and push your code there, or..

```
git checkout master
git merge dev-branch
git push origin master
```

which would merge your changes from `dev-master` into `master` (so master would contain all your commits from dev-branch) then push master to GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this message beacause you have unstaged changes.

In order to push changes to the server you must follow these steps:

1. *Stage changes* : This is when you tell git to track a certain file for changes. You can do this from the command line with : `git add -u <filename>`
   (the `-u` flag only adds files that have been updated, thanks to o11c for the tip!)
2. *Commit changes* : Once you have added all the files to the stage you need to save them locally with `git commit -m "A commit message here"`
3. *Push to server* : Now run `git push origin master`

Do everything in one step:

```
# This adds all updated files in current folder to the stage, 
# then commits with message  and pushes to server


$ git add -u .; git commit -m "[YOUR MESSAGE HERE]"; git push origin master
```

Comment: I follow all this steps

Comment: having all commits with the comment "OK" is not very usefull

Comment: `git add .` is a bad idea since it might add files you *don't* want tracked, `git add -u` is safer since it only adds *changes*, not new files.

Comment: `git add -u` is very nice! Thanks